# Country name in PHP, not showing

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with a code I wrote. I've tested the code several times and it is working just fine, but the thing is that If I run this php file in one specific server (Namecheap) there some functions that don't work correctly and when I run it in another server (1and1) it goes 100% well. I want to get the country name based on the IP to stablish my market and I have a code to do that but in Namecheap, $country_name is not shown but in 1and1 it certenly does. I'm wondering if this could has something to do with PHP version? It would be good if you guys, can refer me to some documentation to see if I'm capable to solve it on my own.

I Hope I'm being clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Links of file on servers are here [Namecheap](http://test.mariageatenerife.fr/logs/) and [1and1](https://myperfectwedding.eu/test/)

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

/* --------------------------------------- /
 * XX. IP and country (Market).
 * -------------------------------------- */

// Gets client's IP.
$ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")?:
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED")?:
getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED")?:
getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

// Matchs gotten IP with API values and retrives location value.
$location = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));

// "Country code to name" array.
$countries = array( "BD" => "Bangladesh", "BE" => "Belgium", "BF" => "Burkina Faso", "BG" => "Bulgaria", "BA" => "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB" => "Barbados", "WF" => "Wallis and Futuna", "BL" => "Saint Barthelemy", "BM" => "Bermuda", "BN" => "Brunei", "BO" => "Bolivia", "BH" => "Bahrain", "BI" => "Burundi", "BJ" => "Benin", "BT" => "Bhutan", "JM" => "Jamaica", "BV" => "Bouvet Island", "BW" => "Botswana", "WS" => "Samoa", "BQ" => "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba ", "BR" => "Brazil", "BS" => "Bahamas", "JE" => "Jersey", "BY" => "Belarus", "BZ" => "Belize", "RU" => "Russia", "RW" => "Rwanda", "RS" => "Serbia", "TL" => "East Timor", "RE" => "Reunion", "TM" => "Turkmenistan", "TJ" => "Tajikistan", "RO" => "Romania", "TK" => "Tokelau", "GW" => "Guinea-Bissau", "GU" => "Guam", "GT" => "Guatemala", "GS" => "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "GR" => "Greece", "GQ" => "Equatorial Guinea", "GP" => "Guadeloupe", "JP" => "Japan", "GY" => "Guyana", "GG" => "Guernsey", "GF" => "French Guiana", "GE" => "Georgia", "GD" => "Grenada", "GB" => "United Kingdom", "GA" => "Gabon", "SV" => "El Salvador", "GN" => "Guinea", "GM" => "Gambia", "GL" => "Greenland", "GI" => "Gibraltar", "GH" => "Ghana", "OM" => "Oman", "TN" => "Tunisia", "JO" => "Jordan", "HR" => "Croatia", "HT" => "Haiti", "HU" => "Hungary", "HK" => "Hong Kong", "HN" => "Honduras", "HM" => "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "VE" => "Venezuela", "PR" => "Puerto Rico", "PS" => "Palestinian Territory", "PW" => "Palau", "PT" => "Portugal", "SJ" => "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "PY" => "Paraguay", "IQ" => "Iraq", "PA" => "Panama", "PF" => "French Polynesia", "PG" => "Papua New Guinea", "PE" => "Peru", "PK" => "Pakistan", "PH" => "Philippines", "PN" => "Pitcairn", "PL" => "Poland", "PM" => "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "ZM" => "Zambia", "EH" => "Western Sahara", "EE" => "Estonia", "EG" => "Egypt", "ZA" => "South Africa", "EC" => "Ecuador", "IT" => "Italy", "VN" => "Vietnam", "SB" => "Solomon Islands", "ET" => "Ethiopia", "SO" => "Somalia", "ZW" => "Zimbabwe", "SA" => "Saudi Arabia", "ES" => "Spain", "ER" => "Eritrea", "ME" => "Montenegro", "MD" => "Moldova", "MG" => "Madagascar", "MF" => "Saint Martin", "MA" => "Morocco", "MC" => "Monaco", "UZ" => "Uzbekistan", "MM" => "Myanmar", "ML" => "Mali", "MO" => "Macao", "MN" => "Mongolia", "MH" => "Marshall Islands", "MK" => "Macedonia", "MU" => "Mauritius", "MT" => "Malta", "MW" => "Malawi", "MV" => "Maldives", "MQ" => "Martinique", "MP" => "Northern Mariana Islands", "MS" => "Montserrat", "MR" => "Mauritania", "IM" => "Isle of Man", "UG" => "Uganda", "TZ" => "Tanzania", "MY" => "Malaysia", "MX" => "Mexico", "IL" => "Israel", "FR" => "France", "IO" => "British Indian Ocean Territory", "SH" => "Saint Helena", "FI" => "Finland", "FJ" => "Fiji", "FK" => "Falkland Islands", "FM" => "Micronesia", "FO" => "Faroe Islands", "NI" => "Nicaragua", "NL" => "Netherlands", "NO" => "Norway", "NA" => "Namibia", "VU" => "Vanuatu", "NC" => "New Caledonia", "NE" => "Niger", "NF" => "Norfolk Island", "NG" => "Nigeria", "NZ" => "New Zealand", "NP" => "Nepal", "NR" => "Nauru", "NU" => "Niue", "CK" => "Cook Islands", "XK" => "Kosovo", "CI" => "Ivory Coast", "CH" => "Switzerland", "CO" => "Colombia", "CN" => "China", "CM" => "Cameroon", "CL" => "Chile", "CC" => "Cocos Islands", "CA" => "Canada", "CG" => "Republic of the Congo", "CF" => "Central African Republic", "CD" => "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "CZ" => "Czech Republic", "CY" => "Cyprus", "CX" => "Christmas Island", "CR" => "Costa Rica", "CW" => "Curacao", "CV" => "Cape Verde", "CU" => "Cuba", "SZ" => "Swaziland", "SY" => "Syria", "SX" => "Sint Maarten", "KG" => "Kyrgyzstan", "KE" => "Kenya", "SS" => "South Sudan", "SR" => "Suriname", "KI" => "Kiribati", "KH" => "Cambodia", "KN" => "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KM" => "Comoros", "ST" => "Sao Tome and Principe", "SK" => "Slovakia", "KR" => "South Korea", "SI" => "Slovenia", "KP" => "North Korea", "KW" => "Kuwait", "SN" => "Senegal", "SM" => "San Marino", "SL" => "Sierra Leone", "SC" => "Seychelles", "KZ" => "Kazakhstan", "KY" => "Cayman Islands", "SG" => "Singapore", "SE" => "Sweden", "SD" => "Sudan", "DO" => "Dominican Republic", "DM" => "Dominica", "DJ" => "Djibouti", "DK" => "Denmark", "VG" => "British Virgin Islands", "DE" => "Germany", "YE" => "Yemen", "DZ" => "Algeria", "US" => "United States", "UY" => "Uruguay", "YT" => "Mayotte", "UM" => "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "LB" => "Lebanon", "LC" => "Saint Lucia", "LA" => "Laos", "TV" => "Tuvalu", "TW" => "Taiwan", "TT" => "Trinidad and Tobago", "TR" => "Turkey", "LK" => "Sri Lanka", "LI" => "Liechtenstein", "LV" => "Latvia", "TO" => "Tonga", "LT" => "Lithuania", "LU" => "Luxembourg", "LR" => "Liberia", "LS" => "Lesotho", "TH" => "Thailand", "TF" => "French Southern Territories", "TG" => "Togo", "TD" => "Chad", "TC" => "Turks and Caicos Islands", "LY" => "Libya", "VA" => "Vatican", "VC" => "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "AE" => "United Arab Emirates", "AD" => "Andorra", "AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda", "AF" => "Afghanistan", "AI" => "Anguilla", "VI" => "U.S. Virgin Islands", "IS" => "Iceland", "IR" => "Iran", "AM" => "Armenia", "AL" => "Albania", "AO" => "Angola", "AQ" => "Antarctica", "AS" => "American Samoa", "AR" => "Argentina", "AU" => "Australia", "AT" => "Austria", "AW" => "Aruba", "IN" => "India", "AX" => "Aland Islands", "AZ" => "Azerbaijan", "IE" => "Ireland", "ID" => "Indonesia", "UA" => "Ukraine", "QA" => "Qatar", "MZ" => "Mozambique" );

// Assigns the location value to the variable "&country_code".
$country_code = $location->country;

// Holds country name value after checking array.
$country_name = $countries[$country_code];

// Posted data.
$posted_data["market"] = $country_name;

// Holds IP value.
$posted_data["ip-address"] = $ip;

/* End of IP and country (Market) */

echo 'IP address: ' . $ip . '<br>Country: ' . $country_name;
```

Comment: Have you tried `$_SERVER` instead of `getenv`?

Comment: The country name is not included in the response. Check Juanra's answer to see how to retrieve it.

Comment: No, I haven't @jotaelesalinas but I will. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: I'll check it @DouwedeHaan. Thanks!

Comment: @jotaelesalinas unfortunally it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

According the ipinfo documentation you should use curl function not file_get_content witch really gets the webpage result not the json data.

```
curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "loc": "37.385999999999996,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "phone": 650
}
```

[Documentation here](http://ipinfo.io/developers)

Here an example with php curl:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

//print_r($result);

$jsonResult = json_decode($result);

echo "Country: ".$jsonResult->country;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hey! @Juanra I saw this yesterday but the truth is that I don't have any clue about curl. So if you gimme so reference guide.

Comment: What I mean is... How could I implement this?

Comment: Hi! @KAZZABE You need to use curl function in your script, as you see here: http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php (there is an example) it is a very useful function.

Comment: Thanks! this is a point of start for me. I will try and I will let you know. Cheers!

Comment: I got some but is not finished yet. But it seems your answer will lead me to solve this. [check here](http://test.mariageatenerife.fr/logs/curl.php)

Comment: is it possible to get some specific value from the curl output?

Comment: Yes of course you only have to parse json data. I will update my first example.

Comment: I was about to comment that I have gotten it with json decode. And you just wrote the solution. I did it but in this way, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your API link is invalid. Use:

`http://ipinfo.io/json` for your own IP

`http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json` for details on another IP.

If you want to get information only about country use:

`http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/country` (without JSON, only plain text)

Your code:

```
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); //or something else ip
$country_code = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$ip/country"); //plain country code, no json
```

(...)

```
// Holds country name value after checking array.
$country_name = $countries[$country_code];
```

Of course `8.8.8.8` change to the correct address

Comment: I'm going to try this out, but I still have a question... why is my original code working and 1and1 server?

Comment: Have you tested this? It didn't work for me, even @ 1and1 is not working. :(

Comment: @KAZZABE Code on these servers (1and1 and Namecheap) is the same?

Comment: Yup! exactly the same. The one posted above!

Comment: @KAZZABE Probobly _1and1_  has other PHP configuration than _Namecheap_. Try to set `allow_url_fopen = On`. [info](http://www.lecoindunet.com/activer-filegetcontent-1and1-mutualise-63). Make a new empty file `php.ini` into where your php script file it is and paste in new file `allow_url_fopen = On`. Or contact the administrators 1and1 and ask for a configuration change, unless you can do it from the admin panel

Comment: From 1and1 [FAQ Site](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/php4-vs-php5-a752479.html)

**allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include**

_Also in PHP5, the variables allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include remain but are disabled or turned OFF by default. This could potentially affect your PHP scripts if either of these directives need to be enabled or turned ON in order for your scripts to function properly. Unless absolutely necessary, these directives should be left disabled as it poses a slight security risk._

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @juanra's answer, I've ended up with the following code.

```
<?php

/* --------------------------------------- /
 * XX. IP and country (Market).
 * -------------------------------------- */

// Gets client's IP.
$ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")?:
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED")?:
getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED")?:
getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

// CURL init. Matchs gotten IP with API values and retrives location value.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
// json output.
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// CURL close.
curl_close($ch);

// "Country code to name" array.
$countries = array( "BD" => "Bangladesh", "BE" => "Belgium", "BF" => "Burkina Faso", "BG" => "Bulgaria", "BA" => "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB" => "Barbados", "WF" => "Wallis and Futuna", "BL" => "Saint Barthelemy", "BM" => "Bermuda", "BN" => "Brunei", "BO" => "Bolivia", "BH" => "Bahrain", "BI" => "Burundi", "BJ" => "Benin", "BT" => "Bhutan", "JM" => "Jamaica", "BV" => "Bouvet Island", "BW" => "Botswana", "WS" => "Samoa", "BQ" => "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba ", "BR" => "Brazil", "BS" => "Bahamas", "JE" => "Jersey", "BY" => "Belarus", "BZ" => "Belize", "RU" => "Russia", "RW" => "Rwanda", "RS" => "Serbia", "TL" => "East Timor", "RE" => "Reunion", "TM" => "Turkmenistan", "TJ" => "Tajikistan", "RO" => "Romania", "TK" => "Tokelau", "GW" => "Guinea-Bissau", "GU" => "Guam", "GT" => "Guatemala", "GS" => "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "GR" => "Greece", "GQ" => "Equatorial Guinea", "GP" => "Guadeloupe", "JP" => "Japan", "GY" => "Guyana", "GG" => "Guernsey", "GF" => "French Guiana", "GE" => "Georgia", "GD" => "Grenada", "GB" => "United Kingdom", "GA" => "Gabon", "SV" => "El Salvador", "GN" => "Guinea", "GM" => "Gambia", "GL" => "Greenland", "GI" => "Gibraltar", "GH" => "Ghana", "OM" => "Oman", "TN" => "Tunisia", "JO" => "Jordan", "HR" => "Croatia", "HT" => "Haiti", "HU" => "Hungary", "HK" => "Hong Kong", "HN" => "Honduras", "HM" => "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "VE" => "Venezuela", "PR" => "Puerto Rico", "PS" => "Palestinian Territory", "PW" => "Palau", "PT" => "Portugal", "SJ" => "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "PY" => "Paraguay", "IQ" => "Iraq", "PA" => "Panama", "PF" => "French Polynesia", "PG" => "Papua New Guinea", "PE" => "Peru", "PK" => "Pakistan", "PH" => "Philippines", "PN" => "Pitcairn", "PL" => "Poland", "PM" => "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "ZM" => "Zambia", "EH" => "Western Sahara", "EE" => "Estonia", "EG" => "Egypt", "ZA" => "South Africa", "EC" => "Ecuador", "IT" => "Italy", "VN" => "Vietnam", "SB" => "Solomon Islands", "ET" => "Ethiopia", "SO" => "Somalia", "ZW" => "Zimbabwe", "SA" => "Saudi Arabia", "ES" => "Spain", "ER" => "Eritrea", "ME" => "Montenegro", "MD" => "Moldova", "MG" => "Madagascar", "MF" => "Saint Martin", "MA" => "Morocco", "MC" => "Monaco", "UZ" => "Uzbekistan", "MM" => "Myanmar", "ML" => "Mali", "MO" => "Macao", "MN" => "Mongolia", "MH" => "Marshall Islands", "MK" => "Macedonia", "MU" => "Mauritius", "MT" => "Malta", "MW" => "Malawi", "MV" => "Maldives", "MQ" => "Martinique", "MP" => "Northern Mariana Islands", "MS" => "Montserrat", "MR" => "Mauritania", "IM" => "Isle of Man", "UG" => "Uganda", "TZ" => "Tanzania", "MY" => "Malaysia", "MX" => "Mexico", "IL" => "Israel", "FR" => "France", "IO" => "British Indian Ocean Territory", "SH" => "Saint Helena", "FI" => "Finland", "FJ" => "Fiji", "FK" => "Falkland Islands", "FM" => "Micronesia", "FO" => "Faroe Islands", "NI" => "Nicaragua", "NL" => "Netherlands", "NO" => "Norway", "NA" => "Namibia", "VU" => "Vanuatu", "NC" => "New Caledonia", "NE" => "Niger", "NF" => "Norfolk Island", "NG" => "Nigeria", "NZ" => "New Zealand", "NP" => "Nepal", "NR" => "Nauru", "NU" => "Niue", "CK" => "Cook Islands", "XK" => "Kosovo", "CI" => "Ivory Coast", "CH" => "Switzerland", "CO" => "Colombia", "CN" => "China", "CM" => "Cameroon", "CL" => "Chile", "CC" => "Cocos Islands", "CA" => "Canada", "CG" => "Republic of the Congo", "CF" => "Central African Republic", "CD" => "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "CZ" => "Czech Republic", "CY" => "Cyprus", "CX" => "Christmas Island", "CR" => "Costa Rica", "CW" => "Curacao", "CV" => "Cape Verde", "CU" => "Cuba", "SZ" => "Swaziland", "SY" => "Syria", "SX" => "Sint Maarten", "KG" => "Kyrgyzstan", "KE" => "Kenya", "SS" => "South Sudan", "SR" => "Suriname", "KI" => "Kiribati", "KH" => "Cambodia", "KN" => "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KM" => "Comoros", "ST" => "Sao Tome and Principe", "SK" => "Slovakia", "KR" => "South Korea", "SI" => "Slovenia", "KP" => "North Korea", "KW" => "Kuwait", "SN" => "Senegal", "SM" => "San Marino", "SL" => "Sierra Leone", "SC" => "Seychelles", "KZ" => "Kazakhstan", "KY" => "Cayman Islands", "SG" => "Singapore", "SE" => "Sweden", "SD" => "Sudan", "DO" => "Dominican Republic", "DM" => "Dominica", "DJ" => "Djibouti", "DK" => "Denmark", "VG" => "British Virgin Islands", "DE" => "Germany", "YE" => "Yemen", "DZ" => "Algeria", "US" => "United States", "UY" => "Uruguay", "YT" => "Mayotte", "UM" => "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "LB" => "Lebanon", "LC" => "Saint Lucia", "LA" => "Laos", "TV" => "Tuvalu", "TW" => "Taiwan", "TT" => "Trinidad and Tobago", "TR" => "Turkey", "LK" => "Sri Lanka", "LI" => "Liechtenstein", "LV" => "Latvia", "TO" => "Tonga", "LT" => "Lithuania", "LU" => "Luxembourg", "LR" => "Liberia", "LS" => "Lesotho", "TH" => "Thailand", "TF" => "French Southern Territories", "TG" => "Togo", "TD" => "Chad", "TC" => "Turks and Caicos Islands", "LY" => "Libya", "VA" => "Vatican", "VC" => "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "AE" => "United Arab Emirates", "AD" => "Andorra", "AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda", "AF" => "Afghanistan", "AI" => "Anguilla", "VI" => "U.S. Virgin Islands", "IS" => "Iceland", "IR" => "Iran", "AM" => "Armenia", "AL" => "Albania", "AO" => "Angola", "AQ" => "Antarctica", "AS" => "American Samoa", "AR" => "Argentina", "AU" => "Australia", "AT" => "Austria", "AW" => "Aruba", "IN" => "India", "AX" => "Aland Islands", "AZ" => "Azerbaijan", "IE" => "Ireland", "ID" => "Indonesia", "UA" => "Ukraine", "QA" => "Qatar", "MZ" => "Mozambique" );

// Assigns ISO Alpha-2 value to the variable "&country_code".
$country_code = json_decode($output, true);

// Assigns "$country_name" value after checking array.
$country_name = $countries[$country_code["country"]];

/* End of IP and country (Market) */

echo 'The country code is: ' . $country_code["country"] . ' and your country is: ' . $country_name . '. Your IP address is: ' . $ip;

?>
```

This is working 100%. Thanks Juanra!